# Custom List EventReceiver Not Working

Tags: event-receivers

Am trying to perform a basic insert to custom list item when an item added from sub-site source list but the insert command don't execute. Any idea?

`Elememnts.xml` setting to hook the receiver:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <Receivers ListUrl="Support/Lists/Suggestions" Scope="Web">
         <Receiver>
         <Name>EventRcvr_MPW_SuggestionItemAdding</Name>
         <Type>ItemAdding</Type>
         <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>
         <Class>PortalV2.EventRcvr_MPW_Suggestion.EventRcvr_MPW_Suggestion</Class>
         <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
  </Receiver>
```

Insert code:

```
 public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
 {
      base.ItemAdded(properties);
      this.EventFiringEnabled = false; //prevent multiple insert

            using (SPWeb web = properties.OpenWeb())
            {
                    SPList list = web.Lists["MyPortalWinner"];
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    SPListItem item = list.Items.Add();
                    item["Title"] = "SUGGESTION";
                    item.Update();
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;


            }

           this.EventFiringEnabled = true; //reset
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify if your event receiver function itself is not called or the code inside event receiver doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @Prakash-CrowCanyon Came to know using SP Manager 2013, the event receiver was not bind to the source list. Most definitely the same reason why ItemAdding() not firing. What am I missing to bind event properly?

Comment: Check if your feature is activated on site and that the feature contains the event receiver.

Comment: @Prakash-CrowCanyon - bit lost here. Appreciate if you can guide me.

Comment: @Prakash-CrowCanyon with vs-debugging the code in itemadded() throws a null exception      using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))    . The MyPortalWinner list is in root... totally lost here.

Comment: SPItemEventProperties has a Site property, please try using it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventproperties.site.aspx

Also, do not dispose this object.

Comment: Appreciate the thoughts. Made it work.

Answer (score 1):

you have to play something on  `ListUrl="Support/Lists/Suggestions"`, try for  `ListUrl="Suggestions"`

Answer (score 0):

Here's how it was fixed.

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
  base.ItemAdded(properties);
  this.EventFiringEnabled = false; //prevent multiple insert

        using (SPWeb web = properties.OpenWeb())
        {
                SPList list = web.Lists["MyList"];
                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                SPListItem item = list.Items.Add();
                item["Title"] = "SUGGESTION";
                item.Update();
                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;

        }

       this.EventFiringEnabled = true; //reset
}
```